# Passing value from activity to Android webview for Javascript method

Tags: javascript, json, android-webview, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass an array from my activity to javascript method in html file located in Assets dir.

I'm using JavascriptInterface passing my int array like JSONArray:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {

        Context mContext;       
        JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {

            mContext = c;

        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public JSONArray getValues() {

            String values = "[100,133,'',120,122,132,133]";

            JSONArray jsonarr = null;

            try {

                jsonarr = new JSONArray(values);

            }

            catch(JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return jsonarr;
        }


    }
```

In javascript method, I take the values thus:

```
    var data = JSON.parse(js.getValues());
```

Now, I'm testing my project on different devices and AVD:

the code works fine on Samsung Note 2 (JB 4.2.1) and on AVD with target Google APIs (API level 8) while on Asus Nexus 7 (JB 4.2.2) and others AVD with JB 4.2 the code stops working returns an Web Console error:

> 03-25 16:35:12.809: E/Web Console(11352): Uncaught SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token o at file:///android_asset/data/test.html:1

I need these values for represent a chart using a Javascript library.

In addition, I modified the file proguard-project.txt denying the javascript code obfuscation:

```
keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
   public *;
}
-keep public class com.XXX.XXX.DataReportActivity$JavaScriptInterface
-keep public class * implements com.XXX.XXX.DataReportActivity$JavaScriptInterface
-keep classmembers class com.XXX.XXX.DataReportActivity$JavaScriptInterface {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
```

does anyone have any idea about solve it?

please, any help is welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Change your Javascript Interface to return a String.  JSON.parse is expecting a string, not a JSON object.

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public String getValues() {
        String values = "[100,133,'',120,122,132,133]";
        return values;
    }
```

The values string might need to be in quotes for the javascript function to be able to parse it too.  In other words:

```
return "'" + values + "'";
```